# codeigniter session without mysql user delete privileges

Tags: codeigniter, session, privileges

I saw online that it is a good practice to use a mysql user account without the 'delete' privileges so that tables will not be "deleted" accidentally or purposely.
But the codeigniter 2xx session needs mysql user with 'delete' privileges to work properly, or else the data in session will not be deleted and will be accumulated...
I was thinking of using cron job to do it offline to delete the database records.
Any online tutorial recommendation for this cron job?
Or any other idea to overcome this, thanks.

### Solved:

I created another user account in codeigniter database config file with the 'delete' privilege.  I then use this special database connection to delete the session database record and close it.  It all happens within the session handling period.